# how to line up 2 divs inside a row div

Tags: html, css

i have a design in mind that would line up a picture of a recipe next to a description text (and link) in a row inside of another bigger div. (named col2) right now the image is beneath the description not on the right of it, were i would like to have it. thanks.

```
 .col2{width:60%;
         background-color: #FFD6AD; 
         border-radius:25px
         color:#993D00;
         padding: 10px;}    

            font-size: 18px;}   

.col2 a {text-decoration:none;
            color: #993D00;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size:20px;}        

.col2 p { max-width:500px;}

.thumb {max-width: 400px;}          

.recipe {max-width: 60%;

            display: -moz-inline-stack;
            display: inline-block;}
```

with the HTML

```
<div class="col2">  
<div "info"> Leckeres essen für wehnig Geld. Es gibt viele Gerichte die
ziemlich günstig sind und trozdem schmecken. </div> 

<div class="recipe"> 
    <div>
        <a href="3bohnen.html"> Chillie aus getrockneten Bohnen </a> 
            <p>Chillie sin carne, oder vegitarisches Chillie .....) </p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb"> <img src="img/sm-chilly.jpg" alt="chilli sin carne">
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general solution would be to float the image to the right, and limit its width using a `%`. [Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z3c1kqcc/).

```
<div class="col2">
    <div class="thumb">
        <img src="img/sm-chilly.jpg" alt="chilli sin carne">
    </div>
    <div "info">Leckeres essen für wehnig Geld. Es gibt viele Gerichte die ziemlich günstig sind und trozdem schmecken.</div>
    <div class="recipe">
        <div> <a href="3bohnen.html"> Chillie aus getrockneten Bohnen </a> 
            <p>Chillie sin carne, oder vegitarisches Chillie .....)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
 .col2 {
     width:60%;
     background-color: #FFD6AD;
     border-radius:25px color:#993D00;
     padding: 10px;
 }
 font-size: 18px;
}
.col2 a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #993D00;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:20px;
}
.col2 p {
    max-width:500px;
}
.thumb {
    float: right;
    max-width: 40%;
}
.thumb img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.recipe {
    max-width: 60%;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

consider adding the image before the text and align it to the left
use span if instead of div if you don't want it to go on a new line

example

```
<div class="recipe"> 
<span class="thumb"> <img src="img/sm-chilly.jpg" align=left alt="chilli sin carne">
    </span>
<span>
    <p><a href="3bohnen.html"> Chillie aus getrockneten Bohnen </a> 
        Chillie sin carne, oder vegitarisches Chillie .....) </p>
</span>
```